# Validation Rule for Picklist

Tags: salesforce1-app, validation

Hi Req as follow : There is two Picklist Values Filed safety Check and Unit Safety Check and another picklist value as Status :

Hence Status must be in the "In Progress" state when there must be some value in Field Safety check and Unit Safety check" also i need to bypass the Profile "System Administrator"  and One Permission Set "FSL"

My Code:

```
AND(
    ($Profile.Name <> "System Administrator"),
    AND(
          ISPICKVAL( Status ,"In Progress" ),
          (ISPICKVAL( Field_Safety_Check__c , '' )),
          (ISPICKVAL( Unit_Safety_Check__c , '')) 
     ))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below rule should meet your requirement

```
AND( 
$Profile.Name <> "System Administrator", 
ISPICKVAL(Status ,"In Progress"), 
OR(
ISPICKVAL(Field_Safety_Check__c , ''), 
ISPICKVAL(Unit_Safety_Check__c , '')
    ) 
)
```

This will throw you an error when any of the two picklist fields are left blank when in In Progress status. If you want to give error only  when both fields are empty, then you will have to remove the OR condition.

The above validation rule bypasses the System Administrator profile. And if you want to bypass this rule for a permission set, there is no direct way to do so. You cannot directly use permission set in validation rule instead you can create a custom permission and bypass the validation rule using that custom permission. You can check this [link](https://sfdcpanther.wordpress.com/2017/12/27/custom-permission-for-validation-rule/) and check for "Solution #3 – Custom Permissions" approach.

Comment: Is there any Possibility to bypass any Permission Set in this code??

Comment: You cannot directly use permission set in validation rule instead you can create a custom permission and bypass the validation rule using that custom permission. You can get further help on [this](https://sfdcpanther.wordpress.com/2017/12/27/custom-permission-for-validation-rule/) link (check for solution 3).

Comment: Yes Thankyou for the help:)